# Every div separately

Tags: jquery, html, find, width

I've got this

```
<div class="projekt">
<div id="main" class="home" role="main"> 
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="projekt">
<div id="main" class="home" role="main"> 
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="slide"><img  src="http://tribulant.net/lightbox/files/2010/08/image-2.jpg" /></div><div class="slide"><img src="http://cyears.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/image4.jpg" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

And jquery:

```
var accum_width = 0;
$('.home').find('.slide').children('img').each(function() {
   accum_width += $(this).width();
});
$('.projekt').width(accum_width);
$('.home').width(accum_width);
```

How to make, that it'l will add the width of images for every .project separatly. Now it's adding width of all images on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the width separately for each .projekt (or .home) class, something like this:

```js
$('.home').each(function () {
    var accum_width = 0;
    $(this).find('.slide').children('img').each(function () {
        accum_width += $(this).width();
    });
    $(this).width(accum_width);
});
```

​